# How to send an email from any Email Address in ASP.Net/C# Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I am a beginner programmer in C#, I want to create a contact form , where the user can enter any email address as the "From" address, and they can send a message. Every time it sends, it says the "From" address is the credentials that I am using. How do I change the From address to the address based on the user's input like any other contact form. Should I use a different Smtp Server?
Thanks

```
    protected void sendbttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
       {



            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(fromtxt.Text);
          
            message.To.Add("toEmail");
            message.Subject = "Subject: " + subjecttxt.Text;
            message.Body = mesgtxt.Text;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
           
           smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
           smtpClient.Port = 587;

        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            
           smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Credemail", "Credpassword");
           
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(message);
            MessageBox.Show("Your email has been sent!");

            fromtxt.Text = "";
            subjecttxt.Text = "";
            mesgtxt.Text = "";
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong, please try again");
        }
```

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. Sending from an address which doesn't match the domain of your email server is a great way to get your email marked as spam or even blocked completely. Use a generic from address on your domain. The address the user enters could always be used as a reply-to address if you wanted

Answer (score 2):

If your host is not registered as official mail provider, you should never even think about sending E-Mail in the name of somebody else.

Instead use a dedicated address as sender and to authenticate at the smart host and remember to store the credentials in a save location so nobody can "adopt" them - the program sourcecode as in the example is definitely not a save place, store them in IIS property fields.

The address entered in the form may be used as reply-to and possibly as the senders display name.

The body will not be html, too. The property therefore should be 'false'.

```
string credMail = "example@gmail.com";
string credPasswd = "example_p@asswd";

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress(credMail,fromtxt.Text);
message.To.Add("toEmail");
message.Subject = "Subject: " + subjecttxt;
message.Body = mesgtxt.Text;
message.IsBodyHtml = false;
message.ReplyToList.Add(fromtxt.Text);

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(credMail, credPasswd);
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Send(message);
MessageBox.Show("Your email has been sent!");
```